# Tweet Button iFrame 107px, how can I change it?

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, twitter, width

I'm using the following code to dynamically add a tweet button to my site so that it loads properly with ajax:

```
var socialHTML = '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="itsYOURDATA" data-url="'+$(location).attr("href")+'" data-text="'+title+'">Tweet</a>';

twttr.widgets.load();
```

It works perfectly fine, it pretty much creates an iFrame where it's supposed to be.  The only problem the iFrame's width is specified in the generated code as 107px, I would like to make this a bit smaller as It doesn't line up very nicely.  Any suggestions?

I tried setting a width for the class in the CSS but it wouldn't take, i think since it's specified inline.

Answer (score 2):

I've actually found the answer to this.

I used the max-width property in CSS:

```
.twitter-share-button {
   max-width:90px;
}
```

But then I realized that this would be too short if the tweets ran into the tens of thousands(which I don't really expect, but who knows).  So I decided to re-order my buttons and leave the twitter button last.